# checkbox don't get first check in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm sorry I'm not that good at English and this is my first time to use this website. So My question might look a little bit strange.

I just wanna make a checkbox. When it got check signal, then I want to make it to express true, and when the checking is removed, then it should express false. But when I use console.log, I found that the first checking don't make any change and after checking is worked like toggle. I don't know why. My code is below, and in third picture, I just checked three time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiB5l.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FazQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdPc7.png)

Comment: Please do not paste images. Paste your real code so we can copy and paste it to help you debug. Regarding images, Do not paste links to external websites. The links might break in future and people coming here might not be able to benefit from this questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your updateIsAgreeInfo to this:-

```js
const updateIsAgreeInfo = () =>{
    setIsAgreeInfo(!isAgreeInfo);
    console.log(isAgreeInfo)
    signupPayload.isAgreeInfo = !isAgreeInfo;
}
```

or send event as a params in updateIsAgreeInfo and then access the current checked value of checkbox using `event.target.checked`. like:-

```js
const updateIsAgreeInfo = () =>{
    setIsAgreeInfo(event.target.checked);
    console.log(event.target.checked)
    signupPayload.isAgreeInfo = event.target.checked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The setState function is async, so in the following lines of code inside your `updateIsAgreeInfo` the state isn't updated yet
You have to store the new value in a variable

Moreover, when setting a state based on old state value, you should use a function in setState instead of the raw value:

```
setIsAgreeInfo((oldValue) => !oldValue);
```